# With R, how can I separate continuous values from a dataframe with item NA and calculate the average of only variable Y?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, na

```
  X Y
1 1 2
2 2 4
3 NA NA
4 NA NA
5 NA NA
6 NA NA
7 1 4
8 2 6
9 1 8
10 1 10
```

It should be so: In the first case the average of the values 2 and 4 is 3 In the second case, the average of the values 4,6,8,10 is 7 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

We can create groups of continuous values using `rleid` from `data.table` , within each group calculate the `mean` of `Y` values/

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(gr = data.table::rleid(is.na(Y))) %>%
  summarise(Y = mean(Y, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Y)) -> df1
df1

#     gr     Y
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1     3
#2     3     7
```

---

`data.table` way of doing this would be :

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- setDT(df)[, .(Y = mean(Y, na.rm = TRUE)), rleid(is.na(Y))][!is.na(Y)]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(X = c(1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
    Y = c(2L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: I have this error: no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"

Comment: @Kerbe Can you test this on the data shared in my post? Does it work for that data?

Comment: @Kerbe You can `select` the columns that you want. To select `gr` column you can do `df1 <- df %>% group_by(gr = data.table::rleid(is.na(Y))) %>% summarise(Y = mean(Y, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% filter(!is.na(Y)) %>% select(gr)`. The output is in `df1`.

Comment: Thank you! I have many data as input and the processing is very slow.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. In your post you have shown and mentioned only about one dataframe and my answer tries to answer the question for it.

Comment: The question was simplified. I read a dataframe with 300k records

Comment: @Kerbe 300K isn't enough records for this to be slow. Nonetheless I have updated the answer to to use `data.table` which should be fast enough. Can you check now?

Answer (score 0):

Your data:

```
df = data.frame(X=c(1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,2,1,1),Y=c(2,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,6,8,10))
```

You can define rows with consecutive rows with no NAs using `diff(complete.cases(..))` :

```
blocks = cumsum(c(0,diff(complete.cases(df)) != 0 ))

block_means = tapply(df$Y,blocks,mean)

 0  1  2 
 3 NA  7

block_means[!is.na(block_means)]
0 2 
3 7
```

Or if you don't need to know the order:

```
na.omit(as.numeric(tapply(df$Y,blocks,mean)))
[1] 3 7
```